# метод получения карты из колоды

Tags: java

```
public Deck() {

    String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    String[] suits = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

    deckOfCards = new Card[52];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++) {
            deckOfCards[suits.length * i + j] = new Card(ranks[i], suits[j]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Как написать метод, который с помощью обычного массива (НЕ arrayList) берет из колоды deckOfCards карту и при этом удаляет ее?

Comment: А что вы хотите видеть на месте удаленной карты в `deckOfCards` ?

Comment: нужно как то удалить ячейку, чтобы при повторном вызове метода не выбрать одну и ту же карту

Comment: а использовать коллекцию вместо массива  не вариант?

Comment: Присваивайте значению массива null, а при выборе проверяйте ее на null.

Comment: Порядок карт в колоде важен?

Comment: `Arrays.shuffle()` и берите последнюю карту (`deckOfCards[deckOfCards.length - 1]`) и присваивайте этому индексу `null`. Еще лучше иметь счетчик карт, чтобы не проверять массив на первый `null`, а итерироватьяс по оставшимся